# C# Moq - alternatives to CallBase when mocking void function

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

CallBase is a function in [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/)  (a C# unit testing library), which allows for easily **hooking into function calls with custom code, while also preserving the base function call**. Its uses and limitations were noted on [this SO post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822947/when-mocking-a-class-with-moq-how-can-i-callbase-for-just-specific-methods).

The primary limitation which that post mentions is that the CallBase function is **not implemented for void functions**.

For example, say we want to mock this Component class:

```
public class Component
{
    public virtual void Do() { /* code */ }
}
```

then I want to use mock to call base AND run custom code...

```
var mock = new Mock<Component>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Do())
    // preserve base call (NOT AN OPTION SINCE VOID FUNCTION!)
    .CallBase()
    .Callback(() => {/* custom test code */});

// if Do() was not a void function, this would be supported by the library
```

One unsatisfying alternative is to change the actual code structure we are testing by splitting the void function into two:

```
public class Component
{
    public virtual void Do() { 
        this.DoInternal();
    }

    internal void DoInternal(){ /* code */ }
}
```

and then...

```
var mock = new Mock<Component>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Do())
    .Callback(() => 
    {
        // my custom code...

        // then call base
        mock.Object.DoInternal();
    });
```

This is not ideal because it requires modifying actual code design/structure purely for testability purposes and is more work/code than would be required if CallBase was natively supported by Moq. Are there alternatives to this work-around? Perhaps implementing an extension to support this outside of the library :

```
public static ICallbackResult<TMock> CallBase<TMock>(this ISetup<TMock> @this)
{
    // not implemented - seems difficult given how little Moq 
    // exposes the underlying implementations which it overrides

    // not sure about ICallbackResult<TMock> being what we'd want for return type...
    // the return type of the actual CallBase function is IReturnsResult<TMock>, but
    // that does not make much sense for a void function
}
```

Let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

There's also a `CallBase` property on mocks. As far as I know, it is supposed to do the same thing as the CallBase() method, just globally for the mock, but with the exception of methods that are explicitly mocked using `Setup()` or something of the sort.

This might not be the best solution either, but you could setup your mock with `.CallBase=true;` and then use explicit `Setup()` method calls on everything where you want mocked to get back the default mocked behavior.

Comment: I actually do have CallBase property set to 'true' on my mocks. You're right that this means that in the absence of Setup being called on a given function, calling that function reverts to the actual base implementation (as opposed to throwing if the mock is Strict, or returning default value if Loose). This unfortunately doesn't help this scenario, though, because we NEED to still call Setup so that we can set up the mock Callback - thus negating the CallBase property behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as of right now `Moq` doesn't have Callbase logic for non-return type methods.

I would suggest:

1. Raise an issue on GitHub and post a comment on this answer, I will try take a look at it + implement
2. Meanwhile, I would recomment not editing your normal code, and create a new class inheriting from `Component` in your test class, that exposes something like the following

`public void DoInternal(){ base.Do(); }`

Then in your call back your can call this.